# concerns about required A records for setting up Firebase Dynamic Links with a custom subdomain

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting, firebase-dynamic-links

In setting up our own subdomain to handle Firebase Dynamic Links using [these docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain), the wizard says to put the A records at [example.com](https://example.com) in our DNS.  I'm getting pushback from our network administrators who are wary of creating an A record at the root of our domain, which is a large e-commerce web site.

A couple of concerns/questions about this:

1. The IP addresses required (151.101.1.195 and 151.101.65.195) point to non-Google servers (looks like [Fastly](https://www.fastly.com/)), which is a bit alarming - it seems strange that Google would outsource their deep link hosting.
2. We don't want all of our e-commerce traffic (coming through [example.com](https://example.com)) to be subject to these A records.  Is it possible to put the A records at [link.example.com](https://link.example.com) instead?

Answer (score 3):

The [Firebase documentation on using a custom domain for dynamic links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains) has this note:

> To use a custom domain for Dynamic Links, the domain must point to Firebase Hosting. If you have a domain you want to use with Dynamic Links and the domain points to a different host, you can either move to Firebase Hosting or **create a subdomain hosted by Firebase, which you can use for Dynamic Links**.

So you can indeed use a subdomain for the dynamic links. In that case, just set up the subdomain in Firebase hosting. You'll need the same `TXT` record as normal, to prove that you have access to the domain, but then just map the subdomain (e.g. `links`) for the `A` record.

Comment: Thanks, @FrankvanPuffelen.  I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I received from Firebase support about these my two concerns/questions:

Regarding Fastly, Firebase uses this subprocessor to deliver content and managed services on Firebase Hosting. For more details you could check the list of Subprocessors used by Firebase on this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/terms/subprocessors).

It's possible to use a subdomain as your Firebase project's FDL domain. You'd need to create a subdomain (link.example.com) on your domain's DNS provider and connect it to Firebase Hosting. You could check out [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains#manual) for more details.

Comment: That seems pretty much the same information as I provided, so I'm not sure it warrants a second answer.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, Thanks again for your help!  I'd agree you covered my question #2 sufficiently.  But support's answer also covers question #1.  And they provided an additional documentation resource to cover the subdomain question.